# Swift and TestFlight works on iOS 8 but not iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, testflight

I've been developing an app (called `Awesome` below) with Swift and distributing it via. TestFlight.

When I build and run the app from Xcode on the iOS 7 and iOS 8 Simulators or on iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices, it works no problem.

When I upload a .ipa file to TestFlight and run it on my iOS 8 iPhone 5, it works no problem.

However, when anyone tries to run it on iOS 7 devices from TestFlight, it shows the launch screen, then crashes. I had one of the testers give me his device Console Log. Here's what he sent me:

```
Jul  7 22:31:53 Test-Device kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[11694] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/A1D07729-70B6-4B23-ADEC-7C78F85FE8D9 (sandbox)
Jul  7 22:31:53 Test-Device networkd[81] <Warning>: Analytics Engine: double ON for app: com.Awesome.Awesome
Jul  7 22:31:53 Test-Device backboardd[31] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'Awesome' access to protected services is denied.
Jul  7 22:31:53 Test-Device Awesome[11694] <Warning>: Unsupported pixel format in CSI
Jul  7 22:31:53 Test-Device Awesome[11694] <Warning>: Unable to create unsliced image from csi bitmap data.
Jul  7 22:31:53 Test-Device Awesome[11694] <Warning>: Could not load the "Logo" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.Awesome.Awesome"
Jul  7 22:31:54 Test-Device ReportCrash[11695] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 11694
Jul  7 22:31:54 Test-Device ReportCrash[11695] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process Awesome[11694]
Jul  7 22:31:54 Test-Device com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.Awesome.Awesome[0xc40d][11694]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.Awesome.Awesome[0xc40d]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Jul  7 22:31:54 Test-Device backboardd[31] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.Awesome.Awesome[0xc40d]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Jul  7 22:31:54 Test-Device ReportCrash[11695] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Awesome_2014-07-07-223154_Test-Device.ips using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly nothing. Xcode 6 is in beta. Part of your app is a small runtime library from Xcode 6. This is supposed to work in iOS 7 when Xcode 6 goes final, but we're not there yet. In short: Your expectations may be too high. But hopefully someone has a real answer for you.

Comment: If you need help because of the app crashing, providing the actual crash report might be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set release optimization level (in build settings) to "None [-oNone]" and it works.